# Need help modifying axis range to accomodate different bar graphs for analysis

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

This is my code that I have tried. I want to change axis labels to highlight differences in each unit.
I am using python version 3.6

```
plt.figure(figsize=(40,20))
logformgraph.plot(kind ='bar')
plt.ylabel('total sales')
plt.title('names by sales')
plt.xticks(rotation= 90)

plt.show()
```

Here is the image

[image]

Can someone help me

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about *"highlight differences in each unit"*? Do you want to change the y-axis or the x-axis labels? Or both? How do you want them to be? By the way, adding `plt.tight_layout()` just before `plt.show()` would help to fit the tick labels into the image. (Also, if possible, try to upgrade your Python version. `3.6` is 4 years old, so you are missing out on many improvements)

Comment: I am trying to modify my axis range to a logarithmetic layout since I transformed the data into a log format

Comment: How do I upgrade to the latest version?